# NullPointerException eventbus subcribe method with Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, greenrobot-eventbus

I call the `EventBus` in `ViewPager.Scroll_State_Dragging` and use it with the subscribe method in fragment, but I removed the syntetic and it still gives the kotlin nullpointer error.

Error Message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: at com.myproject.ui.fragment.MyFragment.onMyEvent (MyFragment.java:93)

MyFragment.java:93 -> binding.textView.text = "worked"
```

SourceCode:

```
class MyEvent
```

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(MyEvent())
```

```
@Subscribe
fun onMyEvent(e: MyEvent?) {
 binding.textView.text = "worked"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EventBus.getDefault().register("Activity Name Here")

Comment: BaseActivity içerisinde register etmiştim zaten, aynı class içerisinde bulunan subscribe methodlarında crash yaşanmıyor. Bu methodda yaşanıyor sadece.